# Double Coset of Upper and Lower triangular matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

This question is from Artin Algebra, Ch 2, Exercise M11(d):

> Most invertible matrices can be written as a product $A=LU$ of a lower triangular matrix $L$ and an upper triangular matrix $U$, where in addition all diagonal entries of $U$ are $1$.
>
> Describe the [double cosets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_coset) $LgU$.
>
> In fact complete exercise is this: [image] where Exer M.9 is this: [image]

I could do this only: $LIU=A$.

**Also**, does there exist unique matrices $P,L',D,U$ for any invertible matrix $A$, such that $PA=L'DU$, where $P$ is permutation matrix, $L'$ is lower triangular matrix with all diagonal entries $1$, $D$ is a diagonal matrix and $U$ (as above,) upper triangular matrix with all diagonal entries $1$. ?

Comment: The point of the exercise is to quantify what is meant by "most".  Here's a hint to get you started.  Try playing around with a $2 \times 2$ matrix $A$.  Something interesting will happen when $a_{11} = 0$.

Comment: Are $L$ and $U$ fixed? Or is $g$ fixed?

Comment: The wording in M.11 is a bit confusing. I think the author meant to ask what $LgU$ is when $g$ is invertible, $L$ is the **set** of all invertible lower triangular matrices and $U$ is the **set** of all invertible upper triangular matrices whose diagonal entries are equal to $1$. In this case the answer is rather obvious if you perform an LPU decomposition on $g$.

Comment: @user1551, if $g=LPU$, then $P\in \{L\}g\{U\}$. Does $\{L\}g\{U\}$ contain any other permutation matrix? (I think u know what i mean by this notation)

Comment: @Silent It would be easier to think of the problem this way: if $P,Q$ are two permutation matrices and $L_1PU_1=L_2QU_2$ are two LPU decompositions, then $LP=QU$ for some $L$ and $U$. Must $P=Q$?

Comment: @user1551 , Wow! No, otherwise $L=U$.

Comment: @user1551, so please check my final verdict: $\{L\}g\{U\}$'s partition $GL_n(\Bbb R)$ and for each permutation matrix, there is one and only one $\{L\}g\{U\}$, ie, permutation matrices are in bijection with $\{L\}g\{U\}$.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't time to answer your questions. I'll let the others speak.